# How do i configure minio using iis as a reverse proxy

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module, minio

I am trying to configure [minio](https://github.com/minio/minio) using IIS as a reverse proxy.

I want the main service to run from `minio.mysite.com` and the console to run from `console.minio.mysite.com`, both of which is already configured with my webhost/dns.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'

networks:
  minio_network2:
    name: minio_network2

services:
  minio_web2:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-10-23T03-28-24Z
    container_name: minio_web2
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: multinerd@mysite.com
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: super_secure_pass
      # MINIO_SERVER_URL: https://minio.mysite.com
      # MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: https://console.minio.mysite.com
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - minio_network2
    volumes:
      - ./minio-data/minio:/data

  minio_nginx2:
    image: nginx:1.19.2-alpine
    container_name: minio_nginx2
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - "3009:9000"  ## Client
      - "30091:9001" ## Console
    depends_on:
      - minio_web2
    networks:
      - minio_network2
```

#### nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream minio {
        server minio_web2:9000;
    }

    upstream console {
        ip_hash;
        server minio_web2:9001;
    }

    server {
        listen       9000;
        listen  [::]:9000;
        server_name  localhost;

        # To allow special characters in headers
        ignore_invalid_headers off;
        # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
        # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
        client_max_body_size 0;
        # To disable buffering
        proxy_buffering off;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_pass http://minio;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       9001;
        listen  [::]:9001;
        server_name  localhost;

        # To allow special characters in headers
        ignore_invalid_headers off;
        # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
        # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
        client_max_body_size 0;
        # To disable buffering
        proxy_buffering off;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            # This is necessary to pass the correct IP to be hashed
            real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            
            # To support websocket
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_pass http://console;
        }
    }
}
```

In IIS, I've set up 2 websites.

##### S_Minio

- binds to minio.mysite.com
- rewrite rules

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RedirectBrowsers" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" negate="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="*firefox*" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="*edge*" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="*chrome*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://console.minio.mysite.com/login" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Docker reverse proxy for minio" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*console*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.200.2.67:3009/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

##### S_Minio_Console

- binds to console.minio.mysite.com
- rewrite rules

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Docker reverse proxy for minio console" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.200.2.67:30091/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Up until this point, everything works well.

If I visit `https://minio.mysite.com`, I get redirected to `https://console.minio.mysite.com`.
I can log in to the console and view my files.

If I try to share a file, the following url gets generated: `http://172.18.0.2:9000/test/my_excel_file.xlsx?query_strings_ommitied` which is no good.

According to the [`things to consider`](https://github.com/minio/minio#things-to-consider) section, I updated my `docker-compose.yml` file with the following changes

```
services:
  minio_web2:
    ...
    environment:
      ...
+      MINIO_SERVER_URL: https://minio.mysite.com
+      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: https://console.minio.mysite.com
```

Now when I log in, I get a error `Post "https://minio.mysite.com/": dial tcp: i/o timeout`.
nginx and my rewrite rules have not changed and im not sure what to change from this point.

Comment: First you need to determine whether the problem occurred in the server before or after the proxy. Try to use failed request tracing to trace requests. If the complete proxy process is recorded in the log, the problem lies in the minio behind the prox

Comment: Apparently I did everything right. There was an issue with docker machine networking, restarting docker machine fixed it.